# What's OrientDB's SQL syntax for inserting a document with an embedded list of other documents?

Tags: sql, orientdb

Let's say we have in our OrientDB (1.7) schema a class Package, which should contain an embedded list of Versions. What's the SQL command to insert into OrientDB a document of the Package type with a list of Versions?

Assume that the current SQL statement to insert a Package, before introducing Versions, looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Package (id) values ("apackage")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create class Version
create property Version.v string
create property Version.release string

create class Package
create property Package.id string
create property Package.versions embeddedlist Version
```

If your situation is the one described above I believe what you're looking for is:

```
insert into Package set id = "apackage", versions = [{"@type":"d","@class":"Version", "v":"1.0.1", "release":"monday"}]
# returns #13:0
```

If you want to add a new version:

```
update #13:0 add versions = [{"@type":"d","@class":"Version", "v":"1.0.2", "release":"tuesday"}]
```